# Re arranging multi dimensional array with std class objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having a multi dimensional array as given before with std objects as well

```
    Array
(
    [0] => abc_Object Object
        (
            [_api:protected] => zvbj
            [_values:protected] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 2
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => abc_Charge Object
                                (
                                    [_api:protected] => zvbj
                                    [_values:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => dGoEw 
                                            [ine] => fKYF0a
                                            [xyz] => abc_Object Object
                                                (
                                                    [_api:protected] => zvbj
                                                    [_values:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => uUmuym
                                                            [last] => 4242
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => abc_Charge Object
                                (
                                    [_api:protected] => zvbj
                                    [_values:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => dblvEw 
                                            [ine] => fKyyu0a
                                            [xyz] => abc_Object Object
                                                (
                                                    [_api:protected] => z7jj
                                                    [_values:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => urtuym
                                                            [last] => 4242
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => abc_Object Object
        (
            [_api:protected] => zvbj
            [_values:protected] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 2
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => abc_Charge Object
                                (
                                    [_api:protected] => zvbj
                                    [_values:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => dGoEw 
                                            [ine] => fKYF0a
                                            [xyz] => abc_Object Object
                                                (
                                                    [_api:protected] => zvbj
                                                    [_values:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => uUmuym
                                                            [last] => 4242
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => abc_Charge Object
                                (
                                    [_api:protected] => zvbj
                                    [_values:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => dblvEw 
                                            [ine] => fKyyu0a
                                            [xyz] => abc_Object Object
                                                (
                                                    [_api:protected] => z7jj
                                                    [_values:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => urtuym
                                                            [last] => 4242
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )                       
)
```

I am trying to combine all these into a much simpler array as

```
Array(
[0]=>(
        [id] => dGoEw 
        [ine] => fKYF0a
        [cid] => uUmuym
    )
[1]=>(
        [id] => dblvEw 
        [ine] => fKyyu0a
        [cid] => urtuym
    )
[2]=>(
        [id] => dGoEw 
        [ine] => fKYF0a
        [cid] => uUmuym
    )
[3]=>(
        [id] => dblvEw 
        [ine] => fKyyu0a
        [cid] => urtuym
    )
)
```

I have tried alot of foreach looping and stuff but i am not able to even print first value of the array. I dont know what i am missing.

```
echo $arr['_api:protected'];
```

**EDIT**

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
        {
            echo $val['_api:protected'];
            print_r($val['_values:protected']);
        }
```

No ouput from this even

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
        {
            $aaa = $val['_values:protected']['data'];
            $arr111['id'] = $aaa['_values:protected']['invoice'];
            $arr111['ine'] = $aaa['_values:protected']['id'];
            $arr111['cid'] = $aaa['_values:protected']['xyz']['_values:protected']['id'];
            $arr222[] = $arr111;
        }
        print_r($arr222);
```

is also not giving me any output. Can anyone please tell me what i am missing?

Comment: Please show what you have tried...

Comment: This issue you are having is because the values are `protected` and you are not doing this from within a context where they are accessible. Does `abc_Charge` extend `abc_Object` or vice versa?

Comment: how can i check that? I am getting this data from a api response in my variable. I am unknown about extentions of them.

Comment: Surely you must have defined the classes `abc_Object` and `abc_Charge` somewhere in your project? Otherwise they would be `stdClass`es...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the properties you are trying to access are defined as [`protected`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) they cannot be accessed unless you are in the context of the class of the object, or a class the extends the class of the object. The `:protected` that you see on the end of the key is not part of the name, it is telling you that the property is defined as `protected`. So the name of the key is not `_values:protected`, it is `_values` and it's visibility is set to `protected`.

Here is a slightly horrible solution with two classes that should allow you to fetch the data from a valid context:

```
<?php

  class simplifier_Object extends abc_Object {

    public static function getIdFromObj ($obj) {
      return $obj->_values['id'];
    }
    public static function getDataFromObj ($obj) {
      return $obj->_values['data'];
    }

  }

  class simplifier_Charge extends abc_Charge {

    public static function getIdFromObj ($obj) {
      return $obj->_values['id'];
    }
    public static function getIneFromObj ($obj) {
      return $obj->_values['ine'];
    }
    public static function getXyzFromObj ($obj) {
      return $obj->_values['xyz'];
    }

  }

  // Assuming that your input array is held in $arr

  $result = array();
  foreach ($arr as $item) {
    foreach (simplifier_Object::getDataFromObj($item) as $sub) {
      $xyz = simplifier_Charge::getXyzFromObj($sub);
      $result[] = array (
        'id' => simplifier_Charge::getIdFromObj($sub),
        'ine' => simplifier_Charge::getIneFromObj($sub),
        'cid' => simplifier_Object::getIdFromObj($xyz)
      );
    }
  }

  var_dump($result);
```

If `abc_Object` extends `abc_Charge` or vice versa, it would be possible to wrap this in a single class that extends the child object, but it still wouldn't be a beautiful solution - someone with a better OO head than mine may have a better idea.

As a side note, you should have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script while developing. If you had, you would have seen many error messages with your code samples above to give you a clue what the problem is.

Comment: thanks alot. Yes there are classes and they have vice versa approach. I took time to understand what you want to tell me. But, now i am done thanks again. Very beautiful way of implementing this feature.